# LaTeX tabular multicolumn produces uneven cell widths

Tags: latex, tabular

Consider following LaTeX-Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    \textbf{Bit $\rightarrow$} & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
    \hline
    Byte 1 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{MQTT Control Packet type} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Flags specific to each MQTT Control Packet type}\\
    \hline
    Byte 2 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Remaining Length}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Why does it look like this? I want the cells on the first row to have the same width!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, no problem:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{p{11mm}|}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Bit $\rightarrow$} & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
    \hline
    Byte 1 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{MQTT Control Packet type} & \multicolumn{4}{p{50mm}|}{Flags specific to each MQTT Control Packet type}\\
    \hline
    Byte 2 & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Remaining Length}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The main thing is to change the line:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
```

to

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|p{11mm}|}
```

or, better, to

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{p{11mm}|}}
```

Then I added some other edits below to adjust alignment and to add vertical lines on the edges of the table (confronting your code with mine won't take you too much time).

The output:

[image: screenshot of output]

I will elaborate some more, by today, to uniform the centered alignment mantaining the fixed width of columns. Feel free to comment meanwhile!

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly how I want the table to look. Still a bit laborious but it works :)

Comment: @binaryBigInt thank you, glad to help! But at least have a look to `\newcolumntype` command from `array` package, to consistently adjust the aligning of all the cells. Example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257128/how-does-the-newcolumntype-command-work